# Vectorization: friend or foe? bsxfun/arrayfun to avoid loops, repmat, permute, squeeze, etc

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, vectorization, bsxfun

This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029235/simplifying-a-computation-so-it-could-be-done-using-matrix-operations) and probably to [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896630/apply-bsxfun-or-arrayfun-to-every-row-of-a-matrix) as well.

Suppose you have two matrices A and B. A is M-by-N and B is N-by-K. I want to obtain an M-by-K matrix C such that `C(i, j) = 1 - prod(1 - A(i, :)' .* B(:, j))`. I have tried some solutions in Matlab - I am here comparing their computation performance.

```
% Size of matrices:
M = 4e3;
N = 5e2;
K = 5e1;

GG = 50;    % GG instances
rntm1 = zeros(GG, 1);    % running time of first algorithm
rntm2 = zeros(GG, 1);    % running time of second algorithm
rntm3 = zeros(GG, 1);    % running time of third algorithm
rntm4 = zeros(GG, 1);    % running time of fourth algorithm
rntm5 = zeros(GG, 1);    % running time of fifth algorithm
for gg = 1:GG

    A = rand(M, N);    % M-by-N matrix of random numbers
    A = A ./ repmat(sum(A, 2), 1, N);    % M-by-N matrix of probabilities (?)
    B = rand(N, K);    % N-by-K matrix of random numbers
    B = B ./ repmat(sum(B), N, 1);    % N-by-K matrix of probabilities (?)

    %% First solution
    % One-liner solution:
    tic
    C = squeeze(1 - prod(1 - repmat(A, [1 1 K]) .* permute(repmat(B, [1 1 M]), [3 1 2]), 2));
    rntm1(gg) = toc;


    %% Second solution
    % Full vectorization, using meshgrid, arrayfun and reshape (from Luis Mendo, second link above)
    tic
    [ii jj] = meshgrid(1:size(A, 1), 1:size(B, 2));
    D = arrayfun(@(n) 1 - prod(1 - A(ii(n), :)' .* B(:, jj(n))), 1:numel(ii));
    D = reshape(D, size(B, 2), size(A, 1)).';
    rntm2(gg) = toc;
    clear ii jj

    %% Third solution
    % Partial vectorization 1
    tic
    E = zeros(M, K);
    for hh = 1:M
      tmp = repmat(A(hh, :)', 1, K);
      E(hh, :) = 1 - prod((1 - tmp .* B), 1);
    end
    rntm3(gg) = toc;
    clear tmp hh

    %% Fourth solution
    % Partial vectorization 2
    tic
    F = zeros(M, K);
    for hh = 1:M
      for ii = 1:K
        F(hh, ii) = 1 - prod(1 - A(hh, :)' .* B(:, ii));
      end
    end
    rntm4(gg) = toc;
    clear hh ii

    %% Fifth solution
    % No vectorization at all
    tic
    G = ones(M, K);
    for hh = 1:M
      for ii = 1:K
        for jj = 1:N
          G(hh, ii) = G(hh, ii) * prod(1 - A(hh, jj) .* B(jj, ii));
        end
        G(hh, ii) = 1 - G(hh, ii);
      end
    end
    rntm5(gg) = toc;
    clear hh ii jj C D E F G

end

prctile([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3 rntm4 rntm5], [2.5 25 50 75 97.5])
%    3.6519    3.5261    0.5912    1.9508    2.7576
%    5.3449    6.8688    1.1973    3.3744    3.9940
%    8.1094    8.7016    1.4116    4.9678    7.0312
%    8.8124   10.5170    1.9874    6.1656    8.8227
%    9.5881   12.0150    2.1529    6.6445    9.5115

mean([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3 rntm4 rntm5])
%    7.2420    8.3068    1.4522    4.5865    6.4423

std([rntm1 rntm2 rntm3 rntm4 rntm5])
%    2.1070    2.5868    0.5261    1.6122    2.4900
```

The solutions are equivalent but the algorithms with partial vectorization are way more efficient in terms of memory and execution time. Even the triple loop seems to perform better than arrayfun! Is there any approach that is actually better than the third, only partially vectorized solution?

**EDIT**: Dan's solutions are the best so far. Let rntm6, rntm7 and rntm8 be the runtime of his first, second and third solution. Then:

```
prctile(rntm6, [2.5 25 50 75 97.5])
%    0.6337    0.6377    0.6480    0.7110    1.2932
mean(rntm6)
%    0.7440
std(rntm6)
%    0.1970

prctile(rntm7, [2.5 25 50 75 97.5])
%    0.6898    0.7130    0.9050    1.1505    1.4041
mean(rntm7)
%    0.9313
std(rntm7)
%    0.2276

prctile(rntm8, [2.5 25 50 75 97.5])
%    0.5949    0.6005    0.6036    0.6370    1.3529
mean(rntm8)
%    0.6753
std(rntm8)
%    0.1890
```

Comment: A note: I would be weary calling `arrayfun` a way to fully vectorize, internally it also just loops. And loops in Matlab these days are actually pretty efficient. So often arrayfun just adds overhead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a minor performance gain with `bsxfun`:

```
E = zeros(M, K);
for hh = 1:M
  E(hh, :) = 1 - prod((1 - bsxfun(@times, A(hh,:)', B)), 1);
end
```

And you could squeeze (pun intended) a tiny bit more performance with this:

```
E = squeeze(1 - prod((1-bsxfun(@times, permute(B, [3 1 2]), A)),2));
```

Or you could try pre-compute the transpose for my first suggestion:

```
E = zeros(M, K);
At = A';
for hh = 1:M
  E(hh, :) = 1 - prod((1 - bsxfun(@times, At(:,hh), B)), 1);
end
```

Comment: Not so minor, actually - see edit above: the mean is halved and the standard deviation is more than halved!

Comment: Slightly slower than your first, but still faster than the others (based on 50 instances).

Comment: Oh - it was faster on my test. OK I'll add one more minor tweak you can try

Comment: Note that when not reordering non-singleton dimensions, a simple `reshape` is usually faster than either `shiftdim` or `permute`. Otherwise this is the right solution IMO.

Comment: @Dan, differences in running time may be due to the performance of different machines. @chappjc, how do you use `reshape` in this context?

Comment: @randomatlabuser I would guess something like changinge `permute(B, [3 1 2])` to `[x,y] = size(B); reshape(B, [1, x, y])`

Comment: @Dan Right. `reshape(B,[1 size(B)])` works too, although `permute` does seem faster here now that I try it. Funny, I have seen the opposite in previous situations.

Answer (score 2):

One situation where you would absolutely benefit from using `arrayfun` or `bsxfun` is where you have Parallel Computing Toolbox available and a compatible NVIDIA GPU. In that case, the performance of those two functions is blazingly fast since the body can be sent to the GPU for execution there. See for example: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/examples/improve-performance-of-element-wise-matlab-functions-on-the-gpu-using-arrayfun.html